# Inaccurate time zone conversion for Altai Standard Time using SQL Server's AT TIME ZONE?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I'm doing development using `AT TIME ZONE` on SQL Server 2019. I noticed that the UTC offset for Altai Standard Time [changes from +07:00 to +06:00 for an hour then changes back](https://dbfiddle.uk/R8tzeOGv):

```
SELECT CAST('20131231 23:59:59' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE N'Altai Standard Time'; -- 2013-12-31 23:59:59 +07:00
SELECT CAST('20140101 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE N'Altai Standard Time'; -- 2013-12-31 23:00:00 +06:00
SELECT CAST('20140101 00:59:59' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE N'Altai Standard Time'; -- 2013-12-31 23:59:59 +06:00
SELECT CAST('20140101 01:00:00' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE N'Altai Standard Time'; -- 2014-01-01 01:00:00 +07:00
```

This didn't seem right to me so I tried to verify the result. ETW tracing suggests that `AT TIME ZONE` calls `mscorlib.ni!TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` in Windows. The Windows time zone change rules in `TimeZoneInfo` have January 1, 2014 as the start of a new rule in which there is a daylight saving time offset switch in October 2014. That seems to match [www.timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/russia/altai?year=2014) which says that there was not a DST switch in 2013 but there was a switch in October of 2014. However, I cannot figure out why there is this one hour period of a changed offset around the start of 2014. Part of the problem is that I do not know of an authoritative source for calculations like this.

Why does `AT TIME ZONE` for Altai Standard Time in SQL Server return an offset of +07:00 for `20131231 23:59:59`, +06:00 for `20140101 00:00:00` and `20140101 00:59:59`, and +07:00 for `20140101 01:00:00`? Could this be a bug in `AT TIME ZONE`?

Comment: Looks like that might be similar to what I've noted here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/09/30/the-mysteries-of-bcl-time-zone-data/

Comment: And yes, it can be reproduced outside SQL Server: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/62cd55dbaa421eb4e9b1a59fa9fa5d78